# mime_types for upload pdf files - symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4, mime-types

I have a file upload field and in my `configure()` I've putted `'mime_types' => 'web_images'` but this give me an error when I upload pdf files... what do I nedd to write instead of `web_images` to be able to upload pdf's? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `'mime_types' => 'web_images'`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set right mime category:

```
$this->setValidator('my_upload_widget', new sfValidatorFile(array(
            'required'        => false,
            'path'            => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_pdf_dir'),
            'mime_categories' => array('pdf' => array('application/pdf', 'application/x-pdf')),
            'mime_types'      => 'pdf'
        )));
```